# Is it okay to install "netdata" on a running server?

Tags: linux, server, centos, monitoring, netdata

The official netdata site recommends installing with the following one-line command:

```
bash <(curl -Ss https://my-netdata.io/kickstart.sh)
```

I have a question here.

Will there be no restarts of various software and processes that are already running
if I run the above command on currently running my server?

For example, 
when the `yum update` command is executed on CentOS, 
docker processes are also affected.
Even, the docker-machine upgrade is going on ...

I'm hesitating to install because of this concern.

Looking forward to a clear answer! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have netdata and as far as I know there's no issues with it, it hasn't stopped any of my docker containers. I recommend setting it up with a reverse proxy via nginx and adding authentication, as having it exposed to the net could be a vulnerability.

Comment: Thank U very much! :)